# Python two loops simultaneously with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tkinter, async-await

I have Tkinter GUI app with two frames. What I want to do is to run two infinity loops at the same time.
While one loop can get data from another.

I have main.py

```
class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
.....
.....

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

And then two frames first is startPage.py which have only button that redirects to experimentPage.py.
And last IMPORTANT frame. experimentPage.py where are these two loops.

```
class experimentPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        // ButtonX that start two loops //
    .... 
    ....
    def loop1(self)
    def loop2(self) // Getting data from loop1
```

What I am trying to do is basically to run loop1 and loop2 simultaneously while loop2 can get data from loop1. Now I am not sure how to achieve that and all my tries failed.

If I understand correctly I have to modify main.py mainloop with asyncio. And modify experimentPage with asyncio too. Using `async def loop1(self)` and that should be all. But whatever I tried ends with an error.

Edit 1 - At this this i have only one loop. But in that one loop i am getting data from eyetracker, drawing them on the screen and doing some calc stuff. Problem is that its gets some delay from where i am actually looking and what is draw. Thats why i want two loops. One for live data from eyetracker. And one for that drawing and calc stuff.

Edit 2 - The problem is i dont know how to edit mainloop correctly to run async taks because everything i found was with threads too. i tried things as app.asyncio.mainloop() which ends with errors like AttributeError: `'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'asyncio'` I am working with python only few days so i may be missing some basic things.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the loops, and not just tkinter. Why do you need two loops? What are they doing what a single loop won't do.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Your question hints towards a flawed approach.

Comment: Thanks for reactions i added them as edits to my question.

Comment: Why don't you want to use threads? Wouldn't that be the obvious solution?

Comment: @wuerfelfreak I thought that async approach is easier then threads thats why i decided for async. But i will probably switch to threads thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use something like this:

```
def loop2(self):
    while !self.stopSignal:
        #do stuff here

def start_loops():
    self.stopSignal = False
    
    thread = threading.Thread(target=loop2, args=(self,))
    thread.start()
    loop1(self)
    self.stopSignal = True
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer to realize that.

In Tkinter,you can use `tk.after`

```py
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image,ImageTk


def take_snapshot():
    print("some one like it")

def video_loop():
    success, img = camera.read()  # read image with camera
    if success:
        # cv2.waitKey(1) # this line is not necessary in Tkinter
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA) #convert color from BGR to RGBA
        current_image = Image.fromarray(cv2image) #convert to Image for Tkinter
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=current_image)
        panel.imgtk = imgtk
        panel.config(image=imgtk)
        root.after(1, video_loop)


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    #camera

root = Tk()
root.title("opencv + tkinter")
#root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', detector)

panel = Label(root)  # initialize image panel
panel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
root.config(cursor="arrow")
btn = Button(root, text="Like!", command=take_snapshot)
btn.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

video_loop()

root.mainloop()
# before quit the program, release all the resources
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```